# Import a file from own project in pod library

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I've installed an open source library with Cocoapods where I can make adjustments but I can't import a file in my own project into the open source file. Is it possible?
Below are the possibilities that I tried

```
// In the open source file
#import "MyClassFileInOwnProject.h"  -- Error: file not found
#import <MyClassFileInOwnProject.h> -- Error: file not found
#import "ProjectFolderName/MyClassFileInOwnProject.h"  -- Error: file not found
#import <ProjectFolderName/MyClassFileInOwnProject.h>  -- Error: file not found
```

Comment: how did you manage your pod ?